# Spring loading and using bean from module

Tags: spring, javabeans, java-module

I have divided my project into 3 modules- client, server, and core. In the core module, I defined the required settings for the sentry. I would like to use those beans in client and server modules so that I don't have to redefine them for each module.

Is it possible? If so please give example.

My current sentry setup in the core module.

> org/project/core/configurations/SentryConfiguration.java

```
package org.project.core.configurations;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;

@Configuration
public class SentryConfiguration {
    /*
        This class is constructed according official sentry documentation.
        URL: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring/
     */

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: „*…I have divided my project into 3 modules…*“ — By „*module*“ do you mean ***JPMS module*** in the same sense as the description of the [*#java-module*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-module) tag: „***Refers to the module as defined by the module system in java introduced in Java 9***“? Or are you using the word *module* in its general sense? The distinction is significant, given what *I think* you're wanting to do. It's important, therefore, that you disambiguate what you mean to make sure you get appropriate and satisfactory answers proposed to you. TIA.

Comment: Also, what do you build this project with? — „*…please give example…*“ — If you push an [*MRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) up to a repo (*plus answer my earlier question and latest question*), I could take a swing at it at some point. TIA.